# LibGDX Texture flickering when moving - nothing seems to fix it

Tags: java, libgdx, textures

I'm getting flickering on tile textures when the player (and hence the camera) move about. It's particularly noticeable if the tile has horizontal or vertical lines on it. I've seen in other places that to solve it I need to set texture filtering to `nearest, nearest` but that is set as default anyway and doesn't solve anything if I explicitly set it either.

Another suggestion is to round the movement position to an integer (which worked for me with another game engine in the past) but seems to do nothing with LibGDX. I noticed in another answer here that the OP said that didn't fix it for him.

I noticed looking at LibGDX game source codes downloaded from Github that they also have texture flickering..is it just normal for LibGDX? It seems very noticeable though...

For example with this type of tile the horizontal lines on it flicker when the player moves up or down.

[image]

**Tried already:**

*rounding movement to integers.*

*setting texture filter to different settings.*

Comment: Rounding camera movement to integers should do the trick as long as you use the default camera viewport since, in that case, a pixel would correspond to a "camera pixel", if you use a custom viewport width or height it will require additional math and who knows what else if the width/height ratio are not the same as the device's screen

Comment: I also noticed this behavior for Textures with very small vertical/horizontal lines.
I solved it by assuring that the cameras position (in scree ncoordinates) is an integer.
To do this, I multiplied the cameras position by the screen/viewport ration, rounded the result and divided it by the ration again:
`float ratioX = viewport.getScreenWidth() / viewport.getWorldWidth();`
`camera.position.x = Math.round(camera.position.x * ratioX) / ratioX;`
You need to do the same for the y-Axis.
I am using Linear/Linear btw.